# It was called "Shimoka Man"

Tags: rules

Many years ago I played a great game but I'm very fuzzy on the details. It went something like this... Deven-card game. Each player gets three cards face down. First player is dealt one card face up, which he can either keep or pass to the player on his left. That player can either keep it or pass it left again, but that player must keep it. This continues until all remaining players have a seven card hand.

Does that ring any bells? After the down cards, all cards were dealt face up. I'm not sure where the next dealt up card goes, and I'm not sure about the betting protocol.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about a game called [Selection, or Rejection](http://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/passthetrash.html#selection) --also known as "Want it? Want it? Got it!" or "Polish".  I've never played it but it does sound like a fun game to try out with friends.  The rules are included in the link: basically, there are 2 down cards, 4 rounds of face-up cards where players can keep or pass the card just as you describe, and then 1 last card face down.  The betting and the determination of the winner of the hand are exactly like 7 card stud, so the only difference is really the passing around of cards in the face-up rounds.